# Setting new value in a grid

Tags: c++

I have a strange issue with an exercise I'm doing (game of life). In the middle bit of code, the line nextgeneration.set(livex, livey, live); causes the program to stop running. Any ideas?

```
int lifeGenerator(Grid<int>& nextgeneration, Grid<int>& birthsanddeaths) {
    for (int deadx = 0; deadx < nrows; deadx++) {
        for (int deady = 0; deady < ncols; deady++) {
            int dead = birthsanddeaths.get(deadx, deady);
            if (dead == -3) {
                nextgeneration.set(deadx, deady, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    for (int livex = 0; livex < nrows; livex++) {
        for (int livey = 0; livey < ncols; livey++) {
            int live = nextgeneration.get(livex, livey);
                if (live > 0 && live < kMaxAge) {
                live++;
                nextgeneration.set(livex, livey, live);// this doesnt work....
                }
            }
        }
    for (int newx = 0; newx < nrows; newx++) {
        for (int  newy = 0; newy < ncols; newy++) {
            int born = birthsanddeaths.get(newx, newy);
            if (born == 3) {
                    nextgeneration.set(newx, newy, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you have posted. So the error is probably somewhere in the code you haven't posted. I would look in two places. 1) the definition of the Grid class, 2) the part of your program where you check the values of nextgeneration, i.e. the bit of the program that makes you think that this code isn't working. Post that code here. (Rereading your post I'm inclined to option 1 as the explanation, but in any case need to see more code).

Comment: Ok. When I say it hangs, it actually stops running. It stops at the line live++, but if I change that to int newlive = live + 1; it stops on the following line. The other nextgeneration.set lines appear to work- I've done cout messages to confirm that the values are right etc. This is main as it stands at the moment, obviously work in progress;

Comment: Ok it was too much text but here's a bit of it;

Comment: It wont let me post it in the comments, too many characters

Comment: Grid<int> birthsanddeaths(nrows, ncols);
    Grid<int> nextgeneration(nrows, ncols);
    nextgeneration = thisgeneration;
    cellFlagger(nextgeneration, birthsanddeaths);
    if (lifeGenerator(nextgeneration, birthsanddeaths) == 0) {
        thisgeneration = nextgeneration;
        display.setDimensions(nrows, ncols);
            for (int x = 0; x < nrows; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < ncols; y++) {
                    if (thisgeneration[x][y] > 0) {
                        int cell = thisgeneration[x][y];
                        display.drawCellAt(x, y, cell);

Comment: Robbie, edit the original question.

Comment: You need to tell us what is the error. Please put a break point (F2 key) at function begging and debug your application. (You need to run it using F5 key, without pressing Ctrl)

Comment: @RobbieCooper You seem reluctant to supply the information need to solve your problem. But looking at you code snippett in the comment above I see that you copy a Grid object here `nextgeneration = thisgeneration;`. So, obvious question, do you have a valid assignment operator written for your Grid class? If you don't then that could be the problem.

Comment: are you pretty sure nrows and ncols initialised properly?

Comment: In the hand outs for the assignment it says to use = to copy grids. It's a Stanford library written for their classes. I'm getting warnings in one menu to update base sdk configuration and remove obsolete build settings etc. I'll try that and see if it makes a difference. Some of the values displayed are bizarre- it shows the value for live as -1339519912 when it should be 6...

Comment: The problem is likely in Grid's operator=(). Post that Grid code?